# Python collections.Counter() runtime

Tags: python, counter

I just run into a problem that I need to put a list, e.g. l = [1, 2, 3, 4], into a dic, e.g. {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}. I just want to know whether I should use collections.Counter() or just write a loop by myself to do this. Is build-in method faster than writing loop by myself?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()` because this what it does. Why to write your own code ;)

Comment: You can always *test* if something is faster, with the `timeit` module. In Python 3, the `Counter` object has C performance improvements and is very fast indeed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I calculated it using `timeit` and My own code is faster than `Counter`. May be I did something wrong, but everything looks same to me

Comment: @anonymous: I did mention that in *Python 3* it is faster. Are you using Python 2 perhaps? See my answer below for a benchmark.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2. May be that is the reason.

Answer (score 5):

You can always *test* if something is faster, with the `timeit` module. In Python 3, the `Counter` object has C performance improvements and is very fast indeed:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random, string
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> def count_manually(it):
...     res = defaultdict(int)
...     for el in it:
...         res[el] += 1
...     return res
...
>>> test_data = [random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(10000)]
>>> timeit('count_manually(test_data)', 'from __main__ import test_data, count_manually', number=2000)
1.4321454349992564

>>> timeit('Counter(test_data)', 'from __main__ import test_data, Counter', number=2000)
0.776072466003825
```

Here `Counter()` was 2 times faster.

That said, unless you are counting in a performance-critical section of your code, focus on readability and maintainability in mind, and in that respect a `Counter()` wins hands-down over write-your-own code.

Next to all that, `Counter()` objects offer functionality on top of dictionaries: they can be treated as *multisets* (you can sum or subtract counters, and produce unions or intersections), and they can efficiently give you the top N elements by count.

Comment: Yes you are right. In Python 2 it is slower, but faster in Python 3

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the **readability** v/s **efficiency**. Let's see both the implementations first. I will be using this as list for the sample run:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Using `collections.Counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(my_list)
```

Using `collections.defaultdict()` creating my own counter:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]: 
    d[i] += 1
```

As you see, **`collections.Counter()` is more readable**

Let see efficiency using `timeit`:

- In *Python 2.7*:

  ```
  mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -c "from collections import defaultdict" "d=defaultdict(int)" "for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]: d[i] += 1"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 2.95 usec per loop

  mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -c "from collections import Counter" "Counter([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2])"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 6.5 usec per loop
  ```

  **`collection.Counter()` implementation is slower by 2 times than own code**.
- In *Python 3*:

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m "timeit" -c "from collections import defaultdict" "d=defaultdict(int)" "for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]: d[i] += 1"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 3.1 usec per loop

  mquadri$ python3 -m "timeit" -c "from collections import Counter" "Counter([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2])"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 5.57 usec per loop
  ```

  **`collections.Counter()` is twice as faster as own code**.

Comment: Still I think it's safe to say that it's O(n) complexity either way.